# Can't retrieve GameObject name from Collider2D list returned by OverlapCircleAll

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection

I'm tying to add a feature that returns all of the objects within a radius of the player. The objects are generated in a pooler from a prefab, and assigned a gameObject.name when instantiated. For some reason, the code below only returns the generic prefab name that the collider is attached to, not the gameObject name assigned to the object immediately after it's instantiated. Any ideas on how to get unique ids from these cloned prefab objects?

```
public class CheckNear : MonoBehaviour
{
    //Nearby Objects//
    public Collider2D[] close = new Collider2D[25];
    public string[] nearRocks = new string[25];
    public Vector3 playerPos;
    private int count;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        playerPos = transform.position;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        close = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(playerPos, 15f, LayerMask.GetMask("Rocks"));

        if (nearRocks.Length >= 10)
        {
            Array.Clear(nearRocks, 0, nearRocks.Length);
            Debug.Log("CLEARED ARRAY");
        }

        foreach (Collider2D j in close)
        {
            if (count <= close.Length)
            {
                count++;
            }
            else if (count >= close.Length)
            {
                count = 0;
            }
            nearRocks[count] = j.gameObject.name;
            Debug.Log("nearRocks Array value:" + nearRocks[count] + "Instance ID:" + j.gameObject.name);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should get clone's name in the scene, that is the generic prefabs name contatenated with '(clone)' which is different from the generic prefab name in the project.
The name is the same for each of the clones if there are many, but the way you explain it is as if you were obtaining the source prebab name and not the cloned in the scene prefab's name. Please clarify if this is the case.

To get and handle the intance of each of the clones in the scene separatedly, maybe what you need is GetInstanceID: `j.gameObject.GetInstanceID()`

Comment: I've tried .GetInstanceID(), but unfortunately the instance ID I get back from j.gameObject.GetInstanceID() is different from when its created. It only assigns one instance id to every object returned from overlap circle. I was trying to assign a name right after instantiating to the top level gameObject.name string and grab that, but only getting generic clone name from gameObjects attached to collider list.

Comment: I am not familier with the use of getdistanceid but a reference of a distance should be the same as long its not destroy and re-created

Comment: on the other hand I would check the references of the objects, mainly the `public string[] nearRocks = new string[25];` to check if everything is ok, with unity stopped and also in runtime